# como identificar si es palíndromo en más de una palabra ingresada por el usuario y presentarlas por pantalla en c++ usando arreglos 3x3

Tags: c++, array, dev-c++, matriz, scanf

necesito ayuda con un código en el cual me permita ingresar varias palabras, en el cual pueda identificar si cada una de las palabras ingresadas es palíndromo o no... para posteriormente sea impreso por pantalla solo las que son palíndromo esto mediante el uso de arrays[x][y];

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
    {
         char vec[9][100], bandera;
         int i, n=9, j, k;
              if(n>1&&n<=9)
             {
                 for(i=0;i<9;i++)
                {
                printf("Ingrese un valor del arreglo:");
                 scanf("%s",&vec[i],100);  
                }
                    k=n-1;
                    for(j=0,k;vec[j]==vec[k];j++,k++)
                   {
                    bandera=1;
                    }
                        if(bandera==0)
                        {
                         printf("\n\nEl arreglo no es palindrome");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                         printf("\n\nEl arreglo si es palindrome"); 
                         }
                  }
                 else
                {
                printf("Ingrese un numero entre el rango 2 y 100");
                }
              getch();
    }
```

Comment: Y qué problema tiene este código? CUál es tu pregunta?

Comment: no tengo problema con el código lo que pasa es que no logro conseguir lo que deseo... es lo puse como tema.
este código lo voy a juntar con otro, pero para ello primero quiero tenerlo separado y luego continuo adaptándolo al código principal, este corresponde a un literal con el que use un switch, que es de buscar palíndromo, hay otra opción que es identificar los verbos y presentarlos, que de igual modo desconozco como se haría

Answer (score 0):

Un string es un vector de caracteres, por lo que puedes recorrer sobre ese string usando `length` para luego ir guardando cada caracter en tu matriz y luego comparar el original con el que invertiste.

```
cin>>palabra;
int a=palabra.lenght();
for(int i=a-1;i>=0;i++) matriz[0]+=palabra[i];
if(matriz[0]==palabra) cout<<"Es palidromo\n";
else cout<<"No es palidromo\n";
```

Esa seria la manera de saber si una palabra es palidromo.

Comment: Uhmmm, intenté colocarlo en mi código pero no me guio donde iría, y ya estoy estresado que no doy más.

Answer (score 0):

> necesito ayuda con un código en el cual me permita ingresar varias palabras, en el cual pueda identificar si cada una de las palabras ingresadas es palíndromo

Eso son dos tareas:

1. Separar una frase en palabras.
2. Identificar palíndromos.

Para lo segundo basta con una sencilla función:

```
bool es_palindromo(const std::string &palabra)
{
    auto cabeza = palabra.begin();
    auto cola = palabra.rbegin();
    const auto longitud = palabra.length() / 2;

    for (int indice = 0; indice != longitud; ++indice, ++cabeza, ++cola)
        if (*cabeza != *cola)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Y lo primero es tan sencillo como leer la entrada de manera natural:

```
int main()
{
    for (std::string palabra; std::cin >> palabra; )
        std::cout << "'" << palabra << "' es palindromo? " << es_palindromo(palabra) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLTsMwEDzHX7EUiSYt0Ipj04YfQUKOs00tubvFjwMgvj3YeZAgH7w7M/aOx@p2e1JGUtt195qUCQ3CUbPzFuW1EjMWEU1tJUTNbADd@00aTY3lK@eKyXlwvjkcBhk8RFbWVhbiW2QyeAYla/yScIKRea6x1ZQX5cSzWbJ2pofbe5FharUPzUJokFp/yQvYwUspRHZmC7kmD9GcVhiV@3Kq705/N5Sw3Q7oY6wGc30VbRQiy/QZ8s3oOR7bTHhm0QdLcJbGYZo39t6G2P4IkUZfZbKent67WQYz2i6HtJQmqKoZTBMGgoOH4xFW61XaRsGAxPBhDv8VesX/D5nST8z6jdYLo/vosusu8hM@AoLFmC4rtH2HBEY6cNjEEY4JAnEq4hK/)</kbd>.

Respecto a los arreglos, no tengo ni la más remota idea de para qué los quieres.

Comment: lo quiero con arreglos... por que ya tengo gestionado el código con arreglos, y no puedo usar ambos... o ingreso palabras con string o con char, pero no puedo hacer ambas, y el codigo usa arreglos, asi que usar string no me sirve, te adjunto parte del código:

int main()
{
int ciclo_A=0,ciclo_B; /

char palabras[9][101]; 

char orden[9][100]; 

char aux[20]; 

la palabra que ingrese en la variable "char palabras[9][101]" es la que quiero verificar si es o no palindromo, pero no es una sola palabra, sonvarias

Comment: Si lo quieres con arreglos estás equivocado. La gestión de cadenas de caracteres usando arreglos de caracteres es una alternativa incómoda, arcaica, propensa a errores y rígida.

Comment: entonces como consigo hacer que una cadena de caracteres usando string, me permita entrar más de 1 palabra?

Comment: Para empezar, redactando bien tu pregunta: especificando que los palíndromos deben ser múltiples palabras no palabras individuales. Para seguir, definiendo de qué manera deben separarse cada uno de los elementos de la frase. Para acabar, separar cada elemento de la frase siguiendo las especificaciones en lugar de separar por espacio.